# In Elixir, why is "alias" preferred over "import" for importing the modules?

Tags: erlang, elixir

> Note that imports are generally discouraged in the language. When working on your own code, prefer alias to import.

I found this statement in the [documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html) but further explanation is not available there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Few reasons:

- `import` creates compile time dependency between these modules, which mean that importing module compilation need to wait until imported module is compiled. `alias` do not create such dependency.
- `import`s often bring too much into scope of the module and can cause compilation conflicts when the imported module will add more functions (you cannot define function with the same name as the imported function).